# Vector Image Representation on 640X480 Screen

Tags: arithmetic

Im trying to learn Computer Graphics. I have the following statement

*For the representation of vector images, we assume that a typical image consists of 500 lines [BHS91]. Each line is deﬁned by its coordinates in the  x  direction and the  y  direction, and by an 8-bit attribute ﬁeld. Coordinates in the  x  direction require 10 bits (log 2 (640)), while coordinates in the  y  direction require 9 bits (log 2 (480)). Bits per line = 9bits + 10bits + 9bits + 10bits + 8bits = 46bits*

I dont understand how 
***Bits per line = 9bits + 10bits + 9bits + 10bits + 8bits = 46bits***
is calculated can someone explain with a little bit demonstration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each line is represented by its two endpoints plus the attribute field. Each endpoint has an $x$-coordinate and a $y$-coordinate. The $x$-coordinate requires $10$ bits while a $y$-coordinate requires $9$. So each point requires $10 + 9$ bits. The attribute field requires an extra $8$, so in total we have

$$(10 + 9) + (10 + 9) + 8 = 46$$

Comment: Thanks,seems much clear now.